# Update Inner Join (update em duas tabelas) - Php; Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner

Tenho duas tabelas e quero fazer uma join para fazer um update nas duas ao mesmo tempo.

Tabela1: `Clipping (id, dia_semana, data)`

Tabela2: `imagemClipping( id, id_clipping, titulo, dia_semana, data, imagem)`

O id_clipping é o dado em comum nelas. Gostaria de editar dia da semana e data. Poderiam me ajudar?

minha consulta:

```
//inicia a edição
$id = $_POST['i'];

//Gravando o nome do arquivo tabela do banco 

$data = $_POST['data'];
$nova_data = implode("-", array_reverse(explode("/", $data)));

$dia_semana = $_POST['dia_semana'];

 $sql = "UPDATE clipping INNER JOIN imagemClipping ON 'clipping.id' = 'imagemClipping.id_clipping'
 SET 'clipping.dia_semana' = clipping.$dia_semana + imagemClipping.$dia_semana,
 'clipping.data' = clipping.$nova_data + imagemClipping.$nova_data WHERE id = $id";
mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

    echo "<script language='javascript'>
 alert('Editou tudo');
 parent.location='cadastro_clipping.php';
   </script>
";
```

Answer (score 3):

Conforme sintaxe abaixo, o **UPDATE** aceita apenas uma tabela. E na clausula **FROM** é possível utilizar mais de uma tabela. Uma recomendação para esses casos é realizar 2 UPDATES separados e envolver os 2 em uma **TRANSACTON**, utilizando *BEGIN TRANSACTION* e *COMMIT TRANSACTION*. Além de um tratamento de erro com *ROLLBACK TRANSACTION*, Pois se ocorrer um erro no segundo UPDATE o primeiro é desfeito. Segue exemplo abaixo, após a sintaxe.

**Sintaxe**

```
UPDATE 
    [ TOP ( expression ) [ PERCENT ] ] 
    { { table_alias | <object> | rowset_function_limited 
         [ WITH ( <Table_Hint_Limited> [ ...n ] ) ]
      }
      | @table_variable    
    }
    SET
        { column_name = { expression | DEFAULT | NULL }
          | { udt_column_name.{ { property_name = expression
                                | field_name = expression }
                                | method_name ( argument [ ,...n ] )
                              }
            }
          | column_name { .WRITE ( expression , @Offset , @Length ) }
          | @variable = expression
          | @variable = column = expression
          | column_name { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
          | @variable { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
          | @variable = column { += | -= | *= | /= | %= | &= | ^= | |= } expression
        } [ ,...n ] 

    [ <OUTPUT Clause> ]
    [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ] 
    [ WHERE { <search_condition> 
            | { [ CURRENT OF 
                  { { [ GLOBAL ] cursor_name } 
                      | cursor_variable_name 
                  } 
                ]
              }
            } 
    ]
```

**Exemplo**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  

BEGIN TRY  

    //Atualizacao da tabela1 com dados da tabela3 com JOIN
    UPDATE dbo.Table1 
    SET dbo.Table1.ColA = dbo.Table3.ColA + dbo.Table3.ColB
    FROM dbo.Table3 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 
    ON (dbo.Table3.ColA = dbo.Table3.ColA);

    //Atualizacao da tabela2 com dados da tabela1 com JOIN
    UPDATE dbo.Table2 
    SET dbo.Table2.ColB = dbo.Table2.ColB + dbo.Table1.ColB
    FROM dbo.Table2 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table1 
    ON (dbo.Table2.ColA = dbo.Table1.ColA);

END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
END CATCH;  

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
GO
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado meu querido!!!

Answer (score 1):

O `JOIN` com `UPDATE` tem a função apenas de contribuir com o filtro dos registros que serão atualizados. Portanto não é possível atualizar duas tabelas com o mesmo `UPDATE`. Neste caso você terá que realmente executar cada update individualmente para sua respectiva tabela.