# Update em duas tabelas MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Como fazer um update em duas tabelas, Ex: primeira tabela `users`, faria update apenas na `senha`, mas na tabela `users_info` faria update cos campos, `cidade`, `nascimento`, `sexo` e etc.

Eu consigo fazer em uma só, mas queria fazer nas duas em uma operacao, li sobre `INNER JOIN`, mas nao entendi muito bem para `update`

`UPDATE ?? SET ?? = ? WHERE ?? = ?`

Comment: o join na sintaxe do update não é para sua situação. No seu caso, deve ser executadas dois comandos de update, o que você pode fazer, é colocar esses dois comandos dentro de uma transação, e assim certificar de que os dois serão executados corretamente.

Comment: Essa pergunta ja foi respondida em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/233300/update-inner-join-php-mysql/233321#233321

Answer (score 0):

Você deve fazer o INNER JOIN através do ID do usuário, e realizar as alterações que quiser. No exemplo abaixo, dei o apelido **u** para a tabela **users**, e **i** para a tabela **users_info**:

```
UPDATE users u INNER JOIN users_info i ON u.id = i.id 
SET u.senha = 'senha', i.cidade = 'cidade', i.nascimento = '1993-01-01', i.sexo = 'F';
```