# Como fazer Update em duas tabelas?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou querendo fazer um `update` em duas tabelas, `postgres`.

Já vi alguns posts utilizando outros bancos e acredito estar fazendo igual, talvez alguma particularidade do banco ou esteja faltando algo. 
[Update em duas tabelas MYSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/234580/update-em-duas-tabelas-mysql)

Tenho 3 tabelas

```
Tipo -> pkey id
Grupo -> pkey id e fkey(idTipo -> Tipo.id)
Produto -> pkey id e fkey(idGrupo -> Grupo.id)
```

Ex: `int id = 10 ; boolean = false;`

Eu desejo utilizar duas instruçoes SQL: a primeira vai ser um update simples que altera a visibilidade(boolean) na tabela tipo.

```
String sql = "update tipo set visibilidade = false where id = 10";
```

a segunda deve alterar os grupos filhos do tipo 10  e sucessivamente os produtos filhos dos grupos filhos do tipo '10' para 'false'.

Tentei assim:

```
UPDATE grupo g
    INNER JOIN produto p on g.id = p.idGrupo
    SET g.visibilidade = false, p.visibilidade = false
    WHERE g.idTipo=10;
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER" LINE 1: UPDATE grupo g
>   INNER JOIN produto p on

Tentei de outra forma, alterando apenas um dos campos...

```
UPDATE produto
SET visibilidade = true
FROM grupo g INNER JOIN produto p on g.id = p.idGrupo
WHERE g.idTipo=10
```

O codigo roda...mas altera todos os registros do banco...
Enquanto o select...

```
select * 
FROM grupo g INNER JOIN produto p on g.id = p.idGrupo
WHERE g.idTipo=10;
```

funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Tenta utilizar ON ao inves de INNER JOIN.

Comment: @DiêgoCorreiadeAndrade seja mais claro por gentileza. Eu já esotu utilizando on....onde quer que coloque on?

Comment: Veja a sintaxe correta do UPDATE no manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html. No lugar desse JOIN utilize a cláusula FROM. Faça dois updates, um para cada tabela, dentro de uma transação.

Comment: Vi o manual mas ainda nao sei como fazer...

Comment: poderia postar os comandos de criação das tabelas envolvidas? Assim acho que consigo montar um exemplo no sqlfiddle.

Comment: "a segunda deve alterar os grupos filhos ... para 'false'." Se entendi bem uma trigger resolveria , não ?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar desta maneira sua sintaxe:

```
UPDATE grupo g
SET g.visibilidade = false, p.visibilidade = false
FROM 'sua tabela'
INNER JOIN produto p on g.id = p.idGrupo 
WHERE g.idTipo=10;
```

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 3:  INNER JOIN produto p on g.id = p.idGrupo

Comment: Vejamos, temos que por um FROM, vou corrigir minha resposta!

Comment: 'sua tabela' qual delas?

Comment: Se não funfar a Produto tenta a grupo... A logica é essa, como se fosse um select

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d065b/1

Comment: Atente ao detalhe de que não funciona no PostgreSQL.

Comment: Sim, no postgres nao funciona.